# AWS Codepipeline deploy execute changeset fail status ROLLBACK_COMPLETE

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-codepipeline

Hello Im new to AWS I stuck with this fail error during my deploy in codepipeline cloudformation.

[image]

There are no error logs ive already short with my resources.
I checked the cloudformation stack

[image]

this is my template:

[image]

[image]

Has anyone any ideas or how to fix this?